# Animation curves in 3D View

Tags: animation, add-on, bezier-curves

[image]

Is it possible to display and edit the selected object/objects animation curves in the viewport like the attached image.

This would be a huge productivity boost.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/motion_trail is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a path from an existing object animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation)

Comment: @David Thanks ..  the download link is broken though.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Not a duplicate question. the curves need to drive the animation, not a visualization of the animation. Editable curves like the Graph Editor.

Comment: OK I just went back and got the link, again, https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/animation_motion_trail.py?view=raw What happened is that it generates a temp url for the raw file, and that is what I had linked to.