# Going from keyframe to curve (Version 2.8)

Tags: animation, camera

I plan to use curves to animate the camera movement.

I can move the view around to create storyboard stills, and when using keyframe animation this could simply be remembered as a keyframe.

But how can I drop a point for drawing a curve, using “here” (the camera view mode) as the point to be marked?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation

Comment: @batFINGER well, those would have been useful for Blender 2.6.