# Interactive motion paths in Blender - do they exist?

Tags: animation, fcurves

In After Effects, you can affect the curve of a motion path without inserting any extra keys:

[image: Straight motion path in After Effects]

Linear, straight motion path

[image: Curved motion path in After Effects]

Same keys, same speed - but now the null will follow a curve

I know Blender has a "calculate motion paths" option where you can see what the motion paths will be, but it seems to have two huge disadvantages: first, you have to manually calculate it each time, and second, you can't drag vertices or handles around to interactively change the interpolation between keys. Also, it's slooooow.

Is there a way to get AE-style, interactive motion paths in Blender somehow? It's a real pain trying to either guess what a curved path will look like in 3d space from the x, y and z paths in the curve editor, or inserting a ton of extra keys I don't need.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation/

Comment: Oh great, hadn't seen that - thank you!