How to convert tracking points into paths



Convert tracking points to paths

What do you want? A straight line from a start position to an end position? Or a more complex curve with intermediate points over time?

Convert any point of the tracking model into a path curve

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation/52831

If I understand the question correctly, you want something like this: a curve that is created by following the movement of an object (here I just used an animated empty):

To do that in Geometry Nodes, use a Simulation Zone and add points on each frame by reading the current Location of the empty from an Object Info node. Then convert the points into a curve:


Thank you, that's what I meant. I have a more complex question. Can we create a mesh based on the volume of an object?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328143/how-to-create-a-plane-based-on-the-trajectory-of-an-object
