How to create a plane based on the trajectory of an object?
How to create a plane based on the trajectory of an object?



How to create a plane based on the trajectory of an object?

My current approach is to create a new plane, dynamically draw it, and then replace it to create it. Is there a better method?

How will your object look like? Will it be just a plane?

The wake of the aircraft needs to be converted into a plane or grid

It's pretty vague, could you please edit your question and give more precisions?

Similar to where a lawn mower has been, there is no grass left. Places that have been visited need to be converted into grids

Create an animation of a lawn mower

Give temporary thickness,  join with previous frame,  convex hull, boolean with the rest,  flatten

I'm not sure that this is what you want but for a lawnmower, create the lawnmower (1), create the surface (2), subdivide it, assign all its vertices to a vertex group, give it a particle system with an object as particle (3), under Vertex Groups > Length > select the vertex group:

Give a Physics > Dynamic Paint to your lawnmower, Type > Brush, click on Add Brush, Source > Paint > Mesh Volume + Proximity. Give a Physics > Dynamic Paint to your surface, Type > Canvas, click on Add Canvas, Surface > Surface Type > Weight, Output > Vertex Group > select the vertex group. Save your file, animate your lawnmower, bake when you're good:


Thank you. Dynamic painting is what I am currently using, and this is how it works. I hope to achieve this using geometric nodes because I need high precision and a lot of subdivisions, which makes it very laggy. I hope geometric nodes can help with this.

Simple planar wake for animated object - Geometry Nodes
Here is a simple way of generating a wake for an animated object.

Start with a vertex at $(0,0,0)$
At each frame, extrude last vertex to current position
Translate geometry to stay fixed according to global position
Convert from mesh to curve, resample
Generate mesh with Curve to Mesh

Here are an animation, the nodes, and the blend file. Feel free to ask if something isn't clear enough.




Thank you for the geometric nodes, which are exactly what I wanted. However, what I need is a complete surface, such as the trajectory of a monkey head generating a monkey head, accurate to the point where the ears brush past, a complete and precise trajectory.

thank! Thank you, can it be a completely accurate path plane that the lawn mower has gone through, without exceeding the left or right plane?

It's already "accurate" per frame. Currently no easy way to have subframe precision. And I don't understand your question.

https://i.sstatic.net/7oYyo7me.jpg

Thank you, I hope we can create a flat mesh based on the volume with precision to the width beyond the ear.

https://i.sstatic.net/fVoU8X6t.jpg

I'll wait for you to explain more precisely your question. Let us know in your original post everything we need to know about what you want exactly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byFPTcmMGNjMHjG-xmD8bkdXHRXgvGq2/view?usp=drive_link

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328159/how-to-obtain-the-volume-of-object-movement-trajectory-and-generate-a-plane
