How to obtain the volume of object movement trajectory and generate a plane?


How to obtain the volume of object movement trajectory and generate a plane?

We need to use geometric nodes to obtain the outermost trajectory during movement and generate a planar mesh

Generate such a grid as smoothly as possible
Google Cloud Drive Source Files
picture



This question is similar to: How to create a plane based on the trajectory of an object?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This problem is to generate a path based on the origin of the object, and my new problem is to generate a mesh plane based on the volume trajectory of the object.

Looks like the very same question to me.

Why? That question is answered and you never explained what is wrong with the answer.

No problem, I'll keep the previous question. The current problem is this. The previous problem was to obtain the trajectory of the object's volume, not the trajectory of the object's origin.

Please explain it properly. Origin, plane and volume are three completely different things, what do you really want?

The origin only generates a curve, and then the plane is obtained by squeezing. I need the trajectory of the overall motion area of the object, which is not the curve generated by the origin of the object's motion.

That's what the answer in the other question is giving you.

Thank you very much for his answer. The one I have been using before is dynamic painting production. I want to use geometric nodes to achieve this, because dynamic painting needs more subdivision, and too laggy needs to be more fluent and accurate.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So, I could come up with these nodes, based on the solution to the previous question, but extruding the entire mesh.
Here I use location and rotation, but there is a limitation: The start frame rotation and location of both objects (source and wake) must be zero! (You achieve this by "apply" rotation and scale at frame 1, and inserting keyframe)
It is possible to improve this, but it will require extra math (no time for that now)
Also, the surface at this point is a total mess (it's not an n-gon). Later I may think of a solution to convert the mess into an n-gon.




Thank you. This model is too complex and cannot be converted from projection cutting. Can we really only use dynamic drawing. thank you

Thank you for your answer. Is there a way for me to obtain the path in the z-axis direction as well.

If you want planes, look for where I multiplied z by zero and change. If you want volumes , just don't flatten Z. (But getting the volume contour without the extra vertices is a whole new issue)
