Path reveal / grow animation using a curve
I want to do a path reveal / pipe growing type animation but can't seem to find a way to do it efficiently. I have a curve and an empty following it. As the empty moves I want it to reveal the curve giving the appearance that it is growing. One way I figured I can do this is by keyframing the Factor End value of the curve under the Start and End Mapping property. So I set the following keyframes:

Empty with Follow Path constraint with Offset factor of 0 at frame 1 and factor of 1 at frame 250
Curve Factor End of 0 at frame 1 and factor of 1 at frame 250

Somehow this doesn't work as expected. The motion of the empty and the curve growth is not in sync even though the start and end values are same over the same number of frame.
Ideally I want the curve growth / reveal effect to be in sync with the movement of the empty or be dictated by the movement of the empty as that's what I will animate.

I tried the Btrace addon as per this answer but did not work for me, likely because my empty is moving too fast.
I'm open to getting this effect in any other way as well (python implementation, geo nodes, etc), just don't want to do it manually by eyeballing the End factor with the empty position. Thanks.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328140/how-to-convert-tracking-points-into-paths
